# case - query optimization

Tags: t-sql

I have this query :

```
INSERT INTO #t1 (VALUE1, VALUE2)
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T2)
THEN SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2 FROM T2
END
```

This does not work , I get : "The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns."

Instead I have to use :

```
INSERT INTO #t1 (VALUE1, VALUE2)
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T2)
THEN SELECT VALUE1 FROM T2
END

CASE
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T2)
THEN SELECT VALUE2 FROM T2
END
```

But this decreases performance. Is there a solution to do it properly? Within a single CASE, to benefit from a sinqle query for the second table t2.

Comment: your query doesn't seem to make sense (`select * from T2` ?). Could you explain with words, and a fake but understandable structure, what you wanna achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T2) doesn't do anything and the syntax is wrong

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO #t1 (VALUE1, VALUE2)
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2 FROM T2
```

This would be valid as well, although not very useful, but it seems it is what you are trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO #t1 (VALUE1, VALUE2)     
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2 FROM T2
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM T2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
INSERT INTO #t1 (VALUE1, VALUE2)
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2 FROM T2
```

If there are no rows in T2 nothing will be inserted into #t1.

Answer (score 0):

Just simplify:

```
INSERT INTO #t1 (VALUE1, VALUE2)
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2
FROM T2
```

The case where there are no rows *doesn't do anything here either*. You don't need to do a special test for that.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use something like

```
  INSERT INTO #t1 (VALUE1, VALUE2)
  SELECT value1, value2 from #t2 WHERE NOT (value1 IS NULL AND value2 IS NULL)
```

instead?

Otherwise your intention might be

```
  INSERT INTO #t1 (VALUE1)
  SELECT CONCAT(value1, value2) from t2 Couldn't you use something like 

  INSERT INTO #t1 (VALUE1, VALUE2)
  SELECT value1, value2 from t2 WHERE NOT (value1 IS NULL AND value2 IS NULL)
```

instead?

Otherwise your intention might be

```
  INSERT INTO #t1 (VALUE1)
  SELECT value1, value2 from #t2 WHERE NOT (value1 IS NULL AND value2 IS NULL)
```

which causes the 't2.value2' to be inserted in t1.value1 if t2.value2 is null